# Setup respeaker pi-hat 2 on RPI ZW

Tags: hardware, audio, pi-zero-w

I am trying to run snips on my rpi0w, and has mounted the respeaker pi hat on to it.

Installed the driver using

```
git clone https://github.com/respeaker/seeed-voicecard
cd seeed-voicecard
sudo ./install.sh 
sudo reboot
```

I disabled the cdmi audio setting in the boot/config such that it only finds the respeaker pi hat 2

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/seeed-voicecard $ aplay -l && arecord -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and my sound.conf looks like this

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/seeed-voicecard $ cat  /etc/asound.conf
# The IPC key of dmix or dsnoop plugin must be unique
# If 555555 or 666666 is used by other processes, use another one


# use samplerate to resample as speexdsp resample is bad
defaults.pcm.rate_converter "samplerate"

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "playback"
    capture.pcm "capture"
}

pcm.playback {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmixed"
}

pcm.capture {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "array"
}

pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    slave.pcm "hw:seeed2micvoicec"
    ipc_key 555555 
}

pcm.array {
    type dsnoop
    slave {
        pcm "hw:seeed2micvoicec"
        channels 2
    }
    ipc_key 666666
}
```

problems is that when i test it by simple recording something, and play the same file

`arecord -d 5 /tmp/test-mic.wav && aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav`

The only thing I hear is noise?
Its as if nothing gets recorded, or not played correctly?

do I have some malfunctioning hardware, or is the config wrong?

Why am not able to play audio and record audio using the respeaker pi hat 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "sam" - , it works like a charm

```
apt-get install sam
sam connect localhost
sam setup audio
```

You should be abale to install it if you made the regular setup with snips

Comment: speaker-test still outputs noise..

Comment: if you did the audio setup with sam , all settings should be fine (check /etc/asound.conf again) - so it looks like a defective respeaker2 or defective speaker itself ... can you check another speaker or that speaker anywhere else ?

Comment: i tried with different hw no change

Comment: I have it on headphones, i assume that sam test only outputs on speaker, hence i am not able to get an output. speaker-test still gives noise